# Unity: Hololens wont run thread when deployed but works in editor

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, uwp, udp, hololens

I'm trying to send a UDP broadcast on the Hololens but for some reason the thread won't get executed. Interestingly, when I compile it on my old laptop in VS it works?! I compared the installed SDK, settings everything but I cannot figure out why it works when I compile it on my old laptop. It was a mere coincidence that I discovered that in the first place.

This calls the thread:

```c#
public void StartThread()
{
    // create thread for reading UDP messages
    readThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReceiveData));
    readThread.IsBackground = true;
    readThread.Start();       
}
```

And the thread looks like this:

```c#
private void ReceiveData()
{
    client = new UdpClient(port);
    client.EnableBroadcast = true;
    Debug.Log("Thread Started");
    while (true)
    {
        try
        ....
```

The debug line won't even get executed. I works in Unity but not on Hololens, except I compile it on an old machine of mine.

Any thoughts? I'm at total loss here.

Comment: Did you try [debugging](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) with an attached Debugger and set breakpoints? Did you also try to just use `... = new Thread(ReceiveData);`?

Comment: Thank you, new Thread(ReceiveData); that did the trick. Yet it makes no sense why it worked on the other deploying machine.

Comment: Yeah `Beginning in version 2.0 of the .NET Framework, it is not necessary to create a delegate explicitly. Specify the name of the method in the Thread constructor,  and the compiler selects the correct delegate.` but as you say it should actually behave the same way I guess.

Answer (score 0):

As derHugo suggested, the thread needed to be started like

```
public void StartThread()
{
    // create thread for reading UDP messages
    readThread = new Thread(ReceiveData);
    readThread.IsBackground = true;
    readThread.Start();       
}
```

That did the trick.